# Should we, by default, migrate cycling questions to Bicycles?

Tags: discussion

We've had some recent questions on bikepacking that I reckon are on topic here, at Travel.se, and Bicycles.se.

Some example cases:

- Mechanical bike questions - I reckon they should always be moved, along with questions about bike-specific equipment.
- Questions about the intersection of cycling and other outdoor activities, like "how do I transport a bike by canoe?" - I reckon they should  *probably* stay here, though "how do I transport a canoe by bike?"  may attract more expertise at Bicycles.
- Trips in which bicycles are incidental might be better handled at Travel...
- unless they're back-country trips,  in which case they might be most appropriate here (e.g. if the focus is camping, but the tent is being carried on a mountain bike - my own [Is it possible to construct an overnight shelter using a bike as the upright?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/58006/is-it-possible-to-construct-an-overnight-shelter-using-a-bike-as-the-upright) could go either way; I posted it at Bicycles, but perhaps there are more creative tarp-users here).

I'm active on all 3 sites, and tend to have a generous interpretation of what's on-topic, so I'm certainly not bothered about where I see them.  But should we move cycling questions as a matter of course?

Comment: Sitting in a hotel room, an example of the 2nd category occurs to me: advice on washing and drying cycling clothing (equally, hiking gear or other technical fabrics) with limited facilities and time. To me, that's best on Travel.

Answer (score 3):

I think your three categories are pretty much spot on. The aim will really to be to get the question to where it has the best likelihood of a good answer. While we have a few cyclists here, Bicycles.SE is full of cyclists, so it makes sense to send them there unless there is a good reason to expect a better answer here (as you point out, likely to be because the question is about camping or something where bicycles are incidental)

Comment: Pretty much my view as well.